# MongoDB Indexes for dynamic sub-fields

Tags: mongodb, exception, indexing, multikey

MongoDB 3.0.2. Documents examples:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), Categories : { "123" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(7), "Clicks" : NumberLong(0) }, "221" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(33), "Clicks" : NumberLong(12) } } }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(2), Categories : { "221" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(33), "Clicks" : NumberLong(12) } } }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(3), Categories : { "123" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(8), "Clicks" : NumberLong(1) } } }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(4), Categories : { "99" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(144), "Clicks" : NumberLong(39) }, "221" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(52), "Clicks" : NumberLong(2) } } }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(5), Categories : { "95" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(18), "Clicks" : NumberLong(3) } } }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(6), Categories : { "123" : { "Shows" : NumberLong(89), "Clicks" : NumberLong(69) } } }
```

In my case in this example string values like "123", "221", "99", "95" is some categories id's. I need sort only by **Shows** using category id:

```
db.myCollection.find().sort( Categories."1".Shows : -1 )
db.myCollection.find().sort( Categories."95".Shows : 1 )
db.myCollection.find().sort( Categories."123".Shows : 1 )
db.myCollection.find().sort( Categories."221".Shows : -1 )
```

But amount of this categories is about 250+. I cant set Indexes for each, like:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( { Categories."[1..250]".Shows : 1 } );
```

because cat id's more than 64 (MongoDB limit) and this categories can be added and deleted to just some records and this process dynamical.

Without indexes i get:

> Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message
>   'localhost:27017: Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data
>   usage of 33554646 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes' in ..

Can someone give a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this using your current document design.

You might want to model your categories in a different way, e.g. using an array for the Categories like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Categories": [
        {
            "CategoryId": "123",
            "Details": {
                "Shows": 7,
                "Clicks": 0
        }, {
            "CategoryId": "221",
            "Details": {
               "Shows": 33,
               "Clicks": 12
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case you can easily add a single index `db.collection.createIndex({"Categories.Details.Shows": 1})`

Comment: But in this case i still cant add indexes for "Shows" fields. I need sort by "Shows" for each category. For your design case db.myCollection.find({"Categories.CategoryId":"123"}).sort( "Categories.Details.Shows" : -1 ) - "Shows"  not indexed.

Comment: @DoanldF I'm sorry that was my mistake. I got the field wrong. But, yes, with this design you can put an index on `Shows`, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using a slightly modified version of dnickless's schema as shown below:
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Categories": [
        {
            "CategoryId": "123",
            "Shows": 7,
            "Clicks": 0
        },
        {
            "CategoryId": "221",
            "Shows": 33,
            "Clicks": 12
        }
    ]
}

You could then create an index on shows.
db.collection.createIndex({"Categories.Shows": 1})
```